# Ember.js: How to create route/controller with single instance of a model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

How can I find a single instance of a model and assign it to a route?

I want the same object from local storage to be the model that a route and it's controller operate on.

I can do this and my view works fine:

```
App.ThingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.createRecord("thing", {name: "Foo"});
  }
});
```

But I cannot find out how to return the FIRST 'thing' record instead of the whole collection. I was hoping for something like:

```
return this.store.find("thing").first();
```

Update (2015-01-28 07:19:00 GMT): I should make clear that I intend for this object to only exist in local storage.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the records that you're trying to access are already loaded you can use:

```
this.store.all('thing').get('firstObject');
```

to get first object of already loaded records collection.

It's a bit trickier when you want to return first object of collection that isn't already loaded:

```
context = this;
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  context.store.find('thing').then(function (things) {
    resolve(things.get('firstObject'));
  });
});
```

Comment: I should have make it clear: I intend for this object to always remain in local storage, so I assume the first example will work for that?

Comment: It depends.  Store.All  doesn't call requests to server etc.  It returns only already loaded records from memory.

Comment: The second example does not work for me (ember 1.9.1, ember-data ~1.0.0-beta.14.1). It gives an error: Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Couldn't find record of type 'thing' for the id 'function (things) { resolve(things.get('firstObject')); }'.